# Button in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to add a `UIButton` into an instance of `UICollectionViewCell`called `MyCollectionViewCell`. I created an outlet in the subclass for the `UIButton` and added the actions in Interface Builder, but I can't seem to get things working correctly.

```
@protocol loadbackgroundDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)loadthebackground:(id)sender;
@end
@interface MyCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *BuyButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *LoadButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<loadbackgroundDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)Loadbackground:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)Buybackground:(id)sender;
@end
```

Has anybody implemented a `UIButton` in `UICollectionViewcell` before , is there is any sample code for this ??

Thank you

Comment: Looks to me like you forgot to connect the buttons / actions, otherwise this shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible, your touch might get delayed because of the contentTouches of the `UICollectionView` which is a `UIScrollView`. The `UIScrollView` delays content touches because first the view tries to figures out if you want to scroll. You could also turn off `delayContentTouches` of your `UICollectionView` but if you have to scroll there might be a delay on scrolling after that.

You can turn it off inside the `UIStoryboard`

[image]